# Extracting "derived" data

Tags: qgis

Rookie Question! I have a shapefile in QGIS 1.8.0 of a country with 20000 divisions. I need the area of each division, but this is not a given attribute. When i click on a district, the "Identify Results" panel shows a "Derived" value for the area of each district along with the feature id. Can somebody tell me how I could extract these area values to a data file? Thanks!!

Comment: follow the steps in the linked question above to create an area column and then save the shapefile (with a new name).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you seek lies here....in the add geometry column.

http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/adding-geometry-columns-to-attribute-table-of-vector-map/

Comment: It seems that someone has marked this question as duplicate. But this question is totally different and unique and specific to question - The link shared above by @Ger is correct and provides the actual solution.